# Is there a way to link/connect two MS SQL databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

The story behind the question is following:
my web host gives me multiple databases, but there are limited in size (just 500 MB) and I am about to run out of space. Is there a way to create another database that is exactly the same structure-wise and somehow link it to the existing database. So every select query searches both databases and insert statements use the new database if there is no space left in the old one?

I know that I can run two queries to search both databases but I do not want to do this...

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best answer: find a new web host who won't limit your database sizes.
Second best answer: use [partitioned views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019.aspx) and then find a new webhost who won't limit your database sizes.

Comment: Hahaha I love your 'Best answer' and as a matter of fact that's exactly what I was thinking... Unfortunately I have prepaid 5 months and do not really want to wast the money. Thanks